# Reconnect disconnected Windows work/school account

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-10

My Windows 10 account on my work machine is part of my work domain. We use Office365, and since being forced to change my Windows password, Outlook stopped working. A Google suggested to disconnect the account from my 'Access work or school' windows settings, then reconnect.

I had both an AzureAD connection and a local AD connection - which, stupidly, I disconnected *both* of them. Windows then immediately logged me out, and I now no longer seem to have my Windows account - I can only log into Windows using the local admin account.

Is there any way to retrieve this account? My `c:\users\dclarke` directory is still there, but seems to have no login associated with it, and I can't access it. Not sure if this makes it harder still, but everyone's UPNs changed a while ago, so my UPN is now `dan.clarke`, not `dclarke` (as per the directory name).